# making connection in viewDidLoad or some where else?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, viewdidload

I have a couple of view controllers and the initial one loads from storyboard with data from a remote xml file at the launch of application.

So I make connection by using NSURLConnection in viewDidLoad to get xml file and parse it. that makes this controller to connect and get data every time it loads.

what should I do to get the initial data(from a remote xml) only at the launch of app or only for first load of the controller rather than every loads of that controller.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, `viewDidLoad` of the root view controller generally is called once and only once the app is started. Your question is suggesting that `viewDidLoad` of your root view controller is getting called more than once, which is usually symptomatic of failure to dismiss/pop back, but rather having circular references between storyboard scenes, which in turn translates to abandoned/leaked memory in your app. Are you really suggesting that `viewDidLoad` of your root view controller being called more than once?

Comment: @Rob I didn't know that.in that case I have been trying something wrong. because viewDidLoad is called whenever that view controller appear.

Comment: Let's imagine you have three view controllers: If you go A -> B -> C -> A, if that final transition from C to A is a present/push segue, then you'll end up with two copies of A sitting in memory. Having gone A -> B -> C, if you want to go back to A, do not present/push to another copy of A, but rather dismiss/pop/unwind back to A. It just depends upon how you're going back to A.

Answer (score 1):

A view controller should never be doing this sort of thing. You should have a model which is fetching the data and the view controller gets the data from the model. Read about MVC, Model View Controller.

If you just want to get something up and running *temporarily* and do a model later, create a boolean flag and set it to true when the data has been fetched and store the flag to NSUserDefaults. When the view loads read the flag from NSUserDefaults to see if you should fetch the data or not.